# Hex string manipulation in Python

Tags: python, string, binary, hex

So I have a string of Hex values that typically goes like this:

```
'\x00\xff\xc0'
```

I need to take each bit (not byte, bit), and print it in an individual line of a table. For instance: if I have `'\xc0'` I need to take the binary value `11000000` and print each individual 1 or 0 in a line. This works fine when functions return an 8 bit binary string, like `\xc0` returns `11000000`. But if I need a `\x00` to be converted to 8 zeros, then it doesn't work.
To better clarify, I need to take a value like `\x01` and print it like this:

```
0 0
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 0
6 0
7 1
```

I tried using

```
bin(ord(value))
```

but had no success, for some values return binary strings with less than 8 bits. Does anyone know how it can be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "no success"? Please be explicit in what problems you've run into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit unclear what you have tried and where the actual issue is. This should get you going, `bintest.py`, please make sure that you understand, step by step, what is happening in that script. You can ask in the comments if something remains unclear.

```
import sys


def bits(byte):
    """Convert byte (byte string of length 1) to bits (int of value,
    0 or 1), most significant bit first.
    """
    byte_as_int = ord(byte)
    for i in reversed(xrange(8)):
        yield (byte_as_int >> i) & 1


# Read byte string from first argument.
bytes = sys.argv[1]


# For each byte in the byte string, print all bit numbers and
# the corresponding bit value, in the format as asked.
for b in bytes:
    for i, bit in enumerate(bits(b)):
        print i, bit
```

Try it out:

```
$ python bintest.py $'\x01'
0 0
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 0
6 0
7 1
```

Notes: The `$'...'` is a neat syntax allowed by bash, it properly parses the \xXX notation. The Python script only works for Python 2 (one of the most relevant point here is that Python 2 does not try to decode argv, argv is accessible in raw binary form). Also note that you cannot use `\x00` in the command line arguments, since it terminates the argument string (it terminates a C char array). You can, however, safely use `\x00` from within the Python script.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def byte2bin(byte_hex):
    return bin(int(byte_hex, 16))[2:].zfill(8)
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
hex = '\x00\xff\xc0'
str.join(' ', (byte2bin(h.encode('hex')) for h in hex))
```

Giving:

```
'00000000 11111111 11000000'
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.x

```
>>> a='\x00\xff\xc0'
>>> ' '.join([bin(ord(x))[2:].zfill(8) for x in a])
'00000000 11111111 11000000'
```